# Macro Scoping to Module

Tags: rust, scope, macros

I'm having some trouble trying to scope a macro.

I have my library `abc` with `lib.rs` that contains only:

```rust
pub mod example;
```

and then in `example.rs` at the same level as `lib.rs`:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! my_example {
    () => {
        no.arg.passed(None)
    };

    ($x:expr) => {
        arg.passed(Some($x))
    };
}
```

I want the `my_example!` macro to be only accessible through `abc::example::my_example!`, however the above code seems to result in it being only accessible through `abc::my_example!`.

I think I may be misunderstanding the `#[macro_export]`'s effect. Any suggestions on how to achieve the module-scoped macro?